# numerical solution of coupled equation

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

```
T := Subscript[φ, n]*Subscript[φ, n];
U := Subscript[φ, n - 1]*Subscript[φ, n - 1];
V := Subscript[φ, n]*Subscript[φ, n - 1];
T := 1;
U := 1;
V := 0;
Solve[{b*A*Subscript[φ, n - 1] + ω*Sqrt[2*n]*B*
     Subscript[φ, n - 1] + κ*B*Subscript[φ,
      n] + Δ*F*Subscript[φ, n - 1] == 
   H*A*Subscript[φ, 
    n - 1], -b*B*Subscript[φ, n] + ω*Sqrt[2*n]*A*
     Subscript[φ, n] + κ*A*Subscript[φ, 
     n - 1] + Δ*G*Subscript[φ, n] == 
   H*B*Subscript[φ, n], 
  b*F*Subscript[φ, n - 1] - ω*Sqrt[2*n]*G*
     Subscript[φ, n - 1] + κ*G*Subscript[φ,
      n] + Δ*A*Subscript[φ, n - 1] == 
   H*F*Subscript[φ, 
    n - 1], -b*G*Subscript[φ, n] - ω*Sqrt[2*n]*F*
     Subscript[φ, n] + κ*F*Subscript[φ, 
     n - 1] + Δ*B*Subscript[φ, n] == 
   H*G*Subscript[φ, n], A^2 + B^2 + F^2 + G^2 == 1}, {A, B, 
  F, G, H}]
```

I want to calculate `A,B,F,G,H` and *Mathematica* is taking too long. Is there any mistake in the code?

Comment: The excessive use of Subscript makes your code incredibly messy when displayed on the website. Why are you defining `T,U,V`, then redefine them, and then you never use them?

Comment: Hi Tayyaba.  Thank you for your question.  Can you please clean up your code by avoiding the use of `Subscript` and the redundant code mentioned by Feyre?  Thanks!

Comment: with all those undefined symbols you do not have a "numerical" problem